# Convert variable to lower string and concatenate

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Why this is not working:

```
MDB="user_"+${PROJECT | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't put the Perl tag unless this is actually a Perl issue.

Comment: It would really help if you include the expected output AND what the value of PROJECT will normally be like, i.e. will it have whitespace in the value. Good luck.

Comment: To execute a command, you use regular parentheses and not curly braces. You also need to put the `$` in front of the variable name, and not outside the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MDB="$(echo "user_$PROJECT" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"
```

(Note: the outer double-quotes aren't strictly necessary here, but there are a lot of places where leaving them out'll cause subtle bugs, so I tend to err on the side of overuse.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with `chcase` ?

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do? Are you attempting to translate whatever `${PROJECT}` is into lower case before setting MDB?

```
MDB="user_$(echo ${PROJECT} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])"
```

The `$(..)` tells the shell to execute the command and replace the text with the standard of that command.

Answer (score 2):

```
MDB="user_${PROJECT}" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"
```

in bash

Comment: MDB="user_${PROJECT}" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"

echo $MDB; is returing a blank string. However echo "user_${PROJECT}" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" is working. I need the result stored in a var.

Comment: That doesn't execute the command. You need to put the commend in "$(..)".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat MDB="user_${PROJECT}| tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' > user_${PROJECT} // OR whatever you want to name your file.
```

Comment: Have you tested this? You're merely putting the string into a file, and you haven't included the closing quote. The "//" doesn't act as a comment in BASH either. Adding cat doesn't do anything since this isn't a file name.

Answer (score 1):

You have a slight syntax error in your bash script.  Modify it just *slightly* so that it looks like the following:

```
MDB="$(echo "user_$PROJECT" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"
```

Good luck!